# improving the efficiency of this jquery selector

Tags: jquery, performance, jquery-selectors

I have a layout similar to this:

```
<li class="item">
  <div class="data">
    <div class="pics">
      <div class="pic"></div>
      <div class="pic"></div>
      <div class="pic"></div>
      <div class="btns">
        <div class="btn 1"></div>
        <div class="btn 2"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <input type="hidden" value="" name="">
  <input type="hidden" value="" name="">
  <input type="hidden" value="" name="">
  <input type="hidden" value="" name="">
</li>
```

What I would like to do is grab all the input elements from the `<li>` when one of the buttons  `class="btn"` is clicked. The way I've approached this is essentially grabbing the `<li>` parent of the button, and then selecting the `<input>` elements...

```
var inputs = $($(element).parents('.item')[0]).children('input');
```

... where `element` is one of the buttons being clicked.

This approach seems to do what I want, but is there a better way to do this? It seems rather inefficient, but I don't have metrics on the performance to know for sure. Any thoughts or suggestions?

### UPDATE

I went to jsPerf to test out my options: http://jsperf.com/jq-select. It seems like what I have is faster than using `closest()`, which I would not have guessed.

Comment: go to http://www.jsperf.com

Comment: I am there... but I only have 1 selector so I don't have a basis for comparison. I'm trying to see if there is an alternative way to do this and compare it to what I have to find a more efficient selector.

Comment: A word on JQuery performance. If you're willing to sacrifice a convenient way of expressing yourself in the name of performance, don't use JQuery. Direct querying of the W3C DOM API can be 1000x faster, at the expense of coding clarity and maintainability. If you need to optimize for JQuery speed for any reason (tight inner loop, etc.) consider taking JQuery *out* of that section of code. Otherwise the performance differences are unnoticable in terms of user experience, dwarfed by things such as rendering, layout, compositing, event bubbling, and everything else the browser is doing.

Comment: thanks @Plynx... that's a good thing to keep in mind. I'm not that concerned about performance so I'll keep jQuery for the sake of clarity :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I find this a little more convenient since it starts from the parent:

```
$('li').has(this).find('input')
```

Performance: http://jsperf.com/jquery-closest-vs-has — note that the best performance comes from caching `$('li')`.

But if you *really* want to see performance, I enhanced your own JSPerf at http://jsperf.com/jq-select/3 with both the cached `li` `has`/`children` approach (about 33% faster than yours) *and* a DOM-only version, just so you can see how huge the gulf really is (not really optimized, but still *7800%* faster!).

This underscores the premise: when speed *really* matters, use DOM. If you're using JQuery, pick the expression you find most convenient and easy to use.

[image]

Comment: I updated my jsPerf with this suggestion and it seems like my original version is still faster. I do like this approach though... definitely cleaner

Comment: I wish I could upvote more than once :P thanks for sharing this! I most likely will stick with jQuery, but this is perfect if I ever decide to do DOM only and need to justify my decision. thanks!

Comment: last note... it seems like `find('input')` outperforms `children('input')` every time

Answer (score 3):

You don't need to invoke the jQuery function twice - you can use `closest`

```
$(element).closest('.item').children('input');
```

Comment: it seems like `closest()` is slower than what I have, but I do like the idea of using this

Answer (score 3):

You could try `closest`:

```
element.closest('.item').children('input');
```

It stops at the first match.

Comment: it seems like `closest()` is slower than what I have, which is not something I would have expected. it is definitely cleaner though, thanks :)